# How to manage quote [ ' ] inside inner html which written as string?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

I am having trouble compile this html code:

```
<div my-directive="'<div ng-class=\'\'my-style-class\' : status.form===\'SUCCESS\' \'>My text</div>\'"></div>
```

`my-directive` gets inner html that my include ng-class with expression.
I have problems with the quote ['] inside the string.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't simply transcluding the html within your directive?

Comment: its directive and it should not have template